# Precompactness and the natural projections

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X_{n},\|\cdot\|_{n})$, for each integer $n\geq 1$, a Banach space and $X:=\prod_{n\geq 1}X_{n}$ their Cartesian product. Define on $X$ the metric

$
d(x,y):=\sup\{\frac{1}{2^{n}}\min\{1,\|x_{n}-y_{n}\|:n\geq 1\} \}
$

for all $x:=(x_{n})_{n\geq 1},y:=(y_{n})_{n\geq 1}\in X$. It is known that $(X,d)$ is a Fréchet space. Also, let $\pi_{n}:X\to X_{n}$ be the natural (or canonical) projection given by

$
\pi_{n}(x):=x_{n}
$

for all $x:=(x_{n})_{n\geq 1}\in X$. Then, I want to prove (if it is true):

**Lemma**: A non-empty subset $B$ of $X$ is precompact if, and only if, $\pi_{n}(B)$ is precompact for all $n\geq 1$.

I have tried the following. Let $U_{n}$ be a neighborhood of the null vector of $X_{n}$. If $B$ is precompact, let $V$ be a  neighborhood  of $0$ (the null vector of $X$) such that $\pi_{n}(V)=U_{n}$. Then, there exists $F:=\{y_{1},\ldots,y_{m}\}\subset  B$ such that $B\subset F+V$. Then, for every $n\geq 1$,  $\pi_{n}(B)\subset \pi_{n}(F)+ U$ and as $\pi_{n}(F)$ is a finite subset of $\pi_{n}(B)$, we find that $\pi_{n}(B)$ is a precompact subset of $X_{n}$.

Reciprocally, assume that for each $n\geq 1$, $\pi_{n}(B)$ is a precompact subset of $X_{n}$. Then, given a neighborhood of the null vector of $X$, put $V$, let $U_{n}:=\pi_{n}(V)$. Then,  there exists $F_{n}:=\{y^{(n)}_{r_{1}},\ldots, y^{(n)}_{m_{n}}\}\subset \pi_{n}(B)$ such that $\pi_{n}(B)\subset F_{n} + U_{n}$.

So, given $\varepsilon >0$ let $n_{0}>1$ such that $2^{-n_{0}}<\varepsilon$ and define

$
F:=\{(y^{(1)}_{r_{j}})_{j\geq 1},\ldots, (y^{(1)}_{m_{j}})_{j\geq 1},\ldots ,(y^{(n_{0})}_{r_{j}})_{j\geq 1} ,\ldots , (y^{(n_{0})}_{m_{j}})_{j\geq 1}\}\subset X
$

I do not know how to continue....Can you help me please?

Many thanks in advance for your comments.

Comment: For one direction you can use that the projections are uniformly continuous (continuous + linear even) so preserve pre-compactness.

Comment: For the other, take all combinations of the finitely many finite sets from the first $n_0$ coordinates, appended with the coordinates from a fixed point from $B$, as the last tail of coordinates do not matter any more.

Comment: Thanks @HennoBrandsma. "For the other" is the direction that I do not know to prove.

Comment: i gave the idea in that comment. Work on it.